# Private messages problem

Tags: privatemsg

In Drupal 6.22, after installing ['User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships)', [APK](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_profile) , [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) and some related social modules. Then upgrading the server (Ubuntu), ans saw that private messages stopped being received by the users.

I have disabled UR, APK et al. and updated the database, but it had not fixed the problem. I even dropped the whole database and used a backup from a time prior to adding social modules. No curing effect.

The server still sends out emails and I am pretty sure that privatemsg permissions are set correctly, so that users should be able to send/receive privatemsges.

This might be clue: The users can receive privatemsg from debug (privatemsg test module), but not from other users. Not sure what does this imply.

I have really ran out of ideas and appreciate your hints.

Comment: What version of Privatemsg?

Comment: It is privatemsg-6.x-1.5. I have also tried the dev version but it caused some 503 errors without fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it had nothing to do with the modules that I thought were culprit. Infact after a lot of experimentation I realized that the issue is caused by Spam module: [6.x-1.3 silently prevents all private messages from being sent](http://drupal.org/node/1248144)

After downgrading to the previous version of Spam, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

So u upgraded Ubuntu, anything else? Php, apache etc? First verify using VMware it is in fact Ubuntu upgrade only that is causing the issue. You say you redeployed an older version of the db.  I would be tempted to do a full deploy just to try to reproduce including Drupal code. It's an odd problem, my instinct says possibly a difference in php version could potentially cause this.

Comment: I agree that it was weird. However it should not be due to PHP or Ubuntu because I am experiencing the massaging being dysfunctional again when I updating some of the modules (I wish I could remember exactly which ones!)